# How do I add icons next to the nodes in a WPF TreeView?

Tags: .net, wpf, treeview

I have a WPF TreeView with just 1 level of items.  The TreeView is data bound to an ObservableCollection of strings.  How can I ensure that the same icon appears to the left of each node in the TreeView?

Answer (score 12):

I think the best approach is to set a Style on the TreeView that will change the Template of the TreeViewItems to have the Image that you want.

The Template will probably need to be a StackPanel with an Image and a label control, you bind the image to your icon, and the label text to the strings from the Observable collection.

I've copied the relevant code snippet from a [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_Explorer_Tree.aspx), which covers this in more detail, but I think the below is all you'll need (This code goes in the TreeView.Resources element).

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Name="img"
                           Width="20"
                           Height="20"
                           Stretch="Fill"
                           Source="image.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="5,0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: This is one icon for all nodes. How to associate different icons for different level of treenodes?

Comment: Use a binding value for the source

Answer (score 12):

I think one of the best articles that will help you to understand the TreeView is this one http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx.  In general, this describes a good set of patterns that can make a lot of scenarios in WPF/SL much easier.

Answer (score 11):

I used [James Osborn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6686/james-osborn)'s [StackPanel technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250597/how-do-i-add-icons-next-to-the-nodes-in-a-wpf-treeview/253243#253243) in this way...

XAML:

```
<TreeView Name="TreeViewThings" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Thing}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                <Image Source="Thing.png"
                       Width="16"
                       Height="16"
                       SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```