# How to add Icons to Treeview in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

I would like to add some icons to my treeview. Is there a way to do it within the XAML?

```
    <TreeView Height="200" Name="treeView1" Width="120">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Topic1" IsExpanded="True">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Subtopic2" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="Subtopic3" />
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my fault. Found same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250597/how-do-i-add-icons-next-to-the-nodes-in-a-wpf-treeview) after posting by similar tags.