# Different icons depending file type WPF in TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have goggled this and there is some information on it [TreeVIew Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266039/different-wpf-treeview-icons-depending-on-the-type-of-node) and [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21248/A-Simple-WPF-Explorer-Tree) which between both they were very helpful. But I still have only same type of file folders.

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="File_Managenment_System.File_Directory"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:uc_tools="clr-namespace:File_Managenment_System"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="File Directory"
        Height="750" 
        Width="900"
        Icon="Pictures\Icon.ico"
        Background="#FF0064FF"
        x:Name="frm_File_Directory"
        Loaded="frm_File_Directory_Loaded">

    <Grid Margin="0,0,2,-3">
        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="840">
            <uc_tools:uc_Toolbar Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450"/>
        </DockPanel>
        <TreeView x:Name="foldersItem"                                  
                  Height="667"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Margin="10,31,591,0"
                  Background="#FFFFFFFF"
                  BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF"
                  Foreground="#FFFFFFFF">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Name="img"
                                   Width="20"
                                   Height="20"
                                   Stretch="Fill"
                                   Source="Pictures\folder.png"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="5,0" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is my WPF, I guess what I don't know what or how to bind to different file types.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see you datacontext, or the datasource for the tree view, but you can bind the Source property of your Image control, to a property in your model that contains the icon:

```
<Image Name="img"
Width="20"
Height="20"
Stretch="Fill"
Source="{Binding FolderIcon}"/>
```

Comment: can you please explain how "{Binding FolderIcon}" works if there is a file type like .docx or .xlsx compared to a folder? O have added the a picture of the tree view/

Comment: @3xGuy **Might be better to use Windows Forms for something like this, but I might be wrong.**